# How to display full screen iAd on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iad

I just recently read that full screen iAd only works on iPad. Do you think it is possbile to show a
full screen iad banner before user to click it on iphone?

Answer (score 4):

Full screen iAd are [ADInterstitialAd](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iAd/Reference/ADInterstitialAd_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html) available only since iOS 4.3 and for **iPad ONLY**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented iad and it seems that they only have landscape and portrait ad banners. But the Ad is Full screen. Once they click on it. It takes over the application and lets you know to pause.

Then lets you know when it is done so you can resume whatever. But again the Ad Banners are only Landscape or Portrait.

Full Screen ipad iad's are listed in the Programming guide .

[iAd Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW16)

Doing a tutorial will get the implementation out pretty fast. But you should go over the manual as well.

Comment: It useful, but close FullScreen iad after press content and then close will crash